# Select mutiple fields from two table in LINQ Select Query using LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to select all CourseInstances (table) left join to Courses table using LINQ; CourseInstances table is left where courses is right table. Now my LINQ query works fine until I add field '_courses.StudyLevelId' in select new {..... I am getting error

### Error

```
The name '_courses' does not exist in the current context
```

I am using LINQPad for testing .... at the bottom I have provided ViewModel approach code...

### LINQ Query

```
from _courseInstances in CourseInstances
join _courses in Courses on _courseInstances.CourseID equals _courses.CourseID into c
from a in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
orderby _courseInstances.CourseCode
select new {_courseInstances.CourseID, _courseInstances.CourseCode, _courseInstances.CourseTitle, _courseInstances.UCASCode, _courseInstances.StartDate, _courses.StudyLevelId }
```

### Generated SQL Script without _courses.StudyLevelId

```
SELECT [t0].[CourseID], [t0].[CourseCode], [t0].[CourseTitle], [t0].[UCASCode], [t0].[StartDate]
FROM [CourseInstances] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Courses] AS [t1] ON [t0].[CourseID] = ([t1].[CourseID])
ORDER BY [t0].[CourseCode]
```

I have created ModelView to tackle multiple tables in single query but I am getting same error

### ViewModel in C#

```
 public class CoursesInstanceStudyLevel_ViewModel
{
    public CourseInstanceModel _CourseInstanceModel { get; set; }
    public CoursesModel _CoursesModel { get; set; }
    public StudyLevelModel  _StudyLevelModel { get; set; }
    public ApplicationURLValidityModel  _ApplicationURLValidityModel { get; set; }
}
```

### C# Linq Query

```
var bb2 = 
 (from _courseInstances in _uof.CourseInstances_Repository.GetAll()
  join _courses in _uof.Courses_Repository.GetAll() on _courseInstances.CourseID equals _courses.CourseID into c
  from a in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
  orderby _courseInstances.CourseCode
  select new CoursesInstanceStudyLevel_ViewModel()
        {
          _CourseInstanceModel = _courseInstances,
          _CoursesModel = _courses
        }).ToList();
```

### with mutiple joins

I am getting following error when I am trying to add multiple join. I believe joins are correct is same where in select{.... where data is null?? UWLApplicationURL = _ApplicationURLValidityRules == null? (bool?)null :  _ApplicationURLValidityRules.UWLApplicationURL }

```
 Error :Cannot assign <null> to anonymous type property
 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'bool'
```

### Code

```
  from _courseInstances in CourseInstances
  join _coursesList in Courses on _courseInstances.CourseID equals _coursesList.CourseID into c
  from _courses in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
  join _ApplicationURLValidityRulesList in ApplicationURLValidityRules on _courseInstances.CourseInstanceID equals _ApplicationURLValidityRulesList.CourseInstanceID into d
  from _ApplicationURLValidityRules in d.DefaultIfEmpty()
  join _studylevel in StudyLevels on _courses.StudyLevelId equals _studylevel.StudyLevelID
  orderby _courseInstances.CourseCode
  select new {_courseInstances.CourseID, _courseInstances.CourseCode, _courseInstances.CourseTitle, _courseInstances.UCASCode, _courseInstances.StartDate, _courses.StudyLevelId, _studylevel.LevelDescription, _studylevel.SLevelType, UWLApplicationURL = _ApplicationURLValidityRules == null? (bool?)null :  _ApplicationURLValidityRules.UWLApplicationURL }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use a instead of _courses:

```
 from _courseInstances in _uof.CourseInstances_Repository.GetAll()
  join _courses in _uof.Courses_Repository.GetAll() on _courseInstances.CourseID equals _courses.CourseID into c
  from a in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
  orderby _courseInstances.CourseCode
  select new CoursesInstanceStudyLevel_ViewModel()
        {
          _CourseInstanceModel = _courseInstances,
          _CoursesModel = a
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: I have update my question. i.e. using viewmodel approach ... also in advanced later on I need to add join on another two tables ... is this approach going to work with that???

Comment: I am getting following error with you approach ..... Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: many thanks it works ... now if need to add join on another two table (next two table with inner join) then it should fine ... right???

Comment: @toxic yes you can join other tables as well

Comment: can you kindly check my last request on this question i will be very thankful to you, I have updated my question at bottom ... getting null error on UWLApplicationURL!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @toxic first try using (object)null instead of (bool?)null only. may be you also need to use (object)_ApplicationURLValidityRules.UWLApplicationURL

Comment: I have realize don't have any data in ApplicationURLValidityRules table and I was trying to join on _ApplicationURLValidityRulesList.CourseInstanceID hence I was not getting any result but now I am ... correct??

Answer (score 0):

I have manage to solve first instance of issue, thanks to Sandeep to giving me idea of where should I look. Next thing I need to check with multiple joins

```
  var bb2 = (from _courseInstances in _uof.CourseInstances_Repository.GetAll()
                     join _coursesList in _uof.Courses_Repository.GetAll() on _courseInstances.CourseID equals _coursesList.CourseID into c
                     from _courses in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     orderby _courseInstances.CourseCode
                     select new CoursesInstanceStudyLevel_ViewModel()
                     {
                         _CourseInstanceModel = _courseInstances,
                         _CoursesModel = _courses 
                     }).ToList();
```